# What should I do when I have date with the NULL features?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, scikit-learn

I have a big amount of data, some of the information is missing (NULL). Should I skip this example in the learning process or do something else?

Comment: NULL data may or may not have and or contribute to structure; you have to determine what to do.

Comment: `NULL` can be data, to.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse at could, but probably in my case it simply means lost information. I am not sure in gives you additional information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on the data and what you think makes sense.  If you think that the NULL information might be meaningful, one option is to create a new variable that denotes the entries that have NULL data.  For example, if you have true/false categorical data with NULL values like

```
1, 0, 1, NULL, NULL, 1, 1, NULL
```

you could transform it to:

```
1  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  <- true
0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  <- false
0  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  <- NULL
```

Something similar can be done with floating point values.

Of course, you could also throw out the NULL values or replace them with an educated guess (maybe the average) if you don't think the fact that they are NULL will be helpful.